# ActionScript Compiler UncaughtErrorEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

After using asc2 to compile the AIR application, I found the error stack trace missing while catching the UncaughtErrorEvent.

Here is the example code:

```
var root:Sprite = this;
root.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR,errorHandle);
throw new Error("test");

protected function errorHandle(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
        {
            var message:String; 
            if (event.error is Error) { 
                message = Error(event.error).message; 
                message+="\n"+Error(event.error).getStackTrace();
            } else if (event.error is ErrorEvent) { 
                message = ErrorEvent(event.error).text;
            } else { 
                message = event.error.toString(); 
            } 
        }
```

While using ASC1, I can see the full stack trace in the error handle.  But using ASC2, just an empty stack trace.

Anyone have the same problem?

How do you get the UncaughtErrorEvent stack trace?

Comment: Was that working when compiling with something else than ASC2?

Comment: First of all, the question is put together so badly I can't edit it to make it readable. It's hard to understand what belongs to each other and I don't understand the question fully. Second of all, you get an error message. You don't provide us code nor tell us on what line in the code that error occurs on. An uncaught error happens when an error is thrown outside of any try..catch blocks or when an ErrorEvent object is dispatched with no registered listeners. You just say "I have an error in my application, help me." How are we supposed to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry for it and I have re-edit it. Is it descripted clearly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't cast `event.error` to `Error`, as in:

```
Error(event.error).getStackTrace()
```

Getting an error's stack trace returns the call stack for an error at the time of the error's construction as a string.  Note that the line number of the stack trace is the line of the cast.

Instead, call `getStackTrace()` from `event.error`, as in:

```
event.error.getStackTrace()
```

There's nothing significant on the stack per your example.

Adding recursion helps demonstrate the issue:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.UncaughtErrorEvent;

    public class ExceptionTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function ExceptionTest()
        {
            super();

            loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);
            recursion();
        }

        protected function recursion(depth:uint=0):void
        {
            if (depth == 5)
                throw new Error("test");
            else
                recursion(++depth);
        }

        protected function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.error.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

...would produce:

```
Error: test
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:19]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:13]
[SWF] Users:jsturges:dev:flash-workspace:X:bin-debug:ExceptionTest.swf - 1,745 bytes after decompression
Error: test
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:19]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:13]
```

If `uncaughtErrorHandler()` is changed to your example casting to `Error`, as in:

```
protected function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(Error(event.error).getStackTrace());
}
```

The debugger catches the exception, but `getStackTrace` is the line of the cast:

```
Error: test
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:19]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest/recursion()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:21]
    at ExceptionTest()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:13]
[SWF] Users:jsturges:dev:flash-workspace:X:bin-debug:ExceptionTest.swf - 1,519 bytes after decompression
Error: Error: test
    at ExceptionTest/uncaughtErrorHandler()[/Users/jsturges/dev/flash-workspace/X/src/ExceptionTest.as:26]
```

There may also be nuances marshaling AS1 and AS2 to AS3 which supports `UncaughtErrorEvent` starting at Flash Player 10.1.

Beyond that, assure appropriate debug player per ActionScript version.  In a non-debugger version of the runtime the `Error.getStackTrace()` method returns `null`.